# Changing column width in grid view for a category using Custom Layout Update

Tags: layout, upgrade, custom

So most of my categories use 3 columns in grid view on category pages. But I have a couple I only show 2 columns and my hope is is to allow for larger product images just for a certain category. Not for every category.

I used a Custom Layout update in the category (see below) to change the number of columns. **Is there a way to change the width of the columns also using a Custom Layout update?**

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>2</columns></action>       
 </reference>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, change of the width would be from css.

I would suggest to add another css from layout update and add css in that file which is only effective on that particular category.

```
    <reference name="head">
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/file.css</name></action>
    </reference>
```

Now, create a css file with your wider width code and place in your template skin path.

Hope this helps.